# Как найти минимальное количество ребер, которое нужно добавить, чтобы граф стал эйлеровым путем или циклом?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, графы, дискретная-математика

Есть некоторые графы, например как на скриншоте. Как узнать, сколько раз (если их рисовать карандашом) надо оторвать карандаш от бумаги, чтобы нарисовать граф.

Граф задается по одной компоненте связности за раз массивом координат вершин. Например:

```
[
    [(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 2), (0, 0)], 
    [(1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (1, 1)]
]
```

То есть это в точности первый граф со скриншота, если считать, что самая левая точка имеет координаты (0, 0).

А массивы координат

```
[
    [(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)], 
    [(0, 2), (0, 3)]
]
```

Это 2 граф, если самая левая точка находится в координатах (0, 0)

[image]

Comment: `<Минимальное необходимое число рёбер> = <число компонент связности> - 1.` Доказательство по индукции. Но формулировки в вопросе и в заголовке разные. Задача в заголовке сложнее.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Вы ответили о получении связного графа, но связный граф - это еще не эйлеров цикл. По-моему, надо сначала добавить ребра для получения связного графа, а потом еще ребра, чтоб осталось не больше двух вершин с нечетной степенью, нет?

Comment: @Harry, согласен.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Тут надо еще как-то подумать, как добавлять ребра связности. Их надо добавлять так, чтоб по возможности не увеличивать при этом количество "нечетных" вершин, но что-то я никак не соображу, как это четко сформулировать математически. Потому что есть варианты, когда это - не увеличение - невозможно, Ощущение, что тут надо чуть ли не динамическое программирование :)

Comment: @Harry, задача перестаёт быть графовой. Записали в каждой компоненте число нечётных вершин, и для этого массива чисел думаете как между ними набросать `k-1` мостик так чтобы нечётных осталось поменьше. Жадного алгоритма не хватит?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Может, вполне хватит, но как это *доказать*?..

Comment: @Harry забыл упомянуть в вопросе, что граф задается по одной компоненте связности за раз, сейчас добавлю. По поводу алгоритма - правильно ли я понимаю, что сначала нужно взять одну компоненту связности и посмотреть степени вершин, если все четные - перехожу к следующей компоненте связности, но что, если есть нечетная вершина или их несколько

Comment: Общий принцип: вы можете нарисовать граф, не отрывая карандаша от бумаги и не проходя дважды по одному ребру (цикл Эйлера), если этот граф односвязен и в нем не более двух вершин с нечетной степенью.

Comment: @Harry а если не могу, то как понять какое минимальное количество раз необходимо поднять карандаш, чтобы нарисовать граф

Comment: Столько, сколько в нем пар нечетных вершин. Если их нет вовсе - рисуется за один раз. N пар - за N раз. Это для односвязного графа.